# Simulation of a discrete pdf

Tags: plotting, simulation, simplex

I have 3 random variables (b,c,d) that capture a discrete pdf over 4 possible realizations. In every period, they evolve according to the random process described in the code below. I would like to simulate the evolution of b,c and d, plotting the resulting paths over time.
I tried with the code below but it does not work. Any suggestion?

````
c0 = 0.25;
d0 = 0.25;
u = 0.3;
z = 0.7;
l = 0.6;
lf = 0.2;
y[b_, c_, d_] := 
  z ((1 - b - c - d) + c) ((1 - lf) b + (1 - l) d) + (l - 
      lf) (d (1 - b - c - d) - b c);
x[b_, c_, 
   d_] := (1 - lf) ((1 - b - c - d) + b (1 - z)) + (1 - l) (c + 
      d (1 - z));
Dtau0[b_, c_, d_] := y[b, c, d]/x[b, c, d];
Dtau1[b_, c_, d_] := y[b, c, d]/(x[b, c, d] (1 - x[b, c, d]));
sigma[b_, c_, d_] := 
  Piecewise[{{1, u >= Dtau1[b, c, d]}, {0, 
     u <= y[b, c, d]/x[b, c, d]}, {(1 - y[b, c, d]/(u x[b, c, d]))*1/
      x[b, c, d], Dtau0[b, c, d] < u < Dtau1[b, c, d]}}];
p0[b_, c_, 
   d_] := ((1 - lf) sigma[b, c, d]) (1 - b - c - 
      d) + ((1 - lf) (1 - z) sigma[b, c, 
       d]) b + ((1 - l) s) c + ((1 - l) (1 - z) sigma[b, c, d]) d;
nextb[b_, c_, d_] := 
  RandomChoice[{l + (1 - l) (z + (1 - z) (1 - sigma[b, c, d])), 
     1 - l - (1 - 
         l) (z + (1 - z) (1 - sigma[b, c, d]))} -> {((lf + (1 - 
           lf) (z + (1 - z) (1 - signa[b, c, d]))) b)/(
     1 - p0[b, c, d]), (((1 - lf) (1 - z) s) b)/p0[b, c, d]}];
nextc[b_, c_, d_] := 
  RandomChoice[{l + (1 - l) (z + (1 - z) (1 - sigma[b, c, d])), 
     1 - l - (1 - 
         l) (z + (1 - z) (1 - sigma[b, c, d]))} -> {((l + (1 - l) (1 -
            sigma[b, c, d])) c)/(
     1 - p0[b, c, d]), (((1 - l) sigma[b, c, d]) c)/p0[b, c, d]}];
nextd[b_, c_, d_] := 
  RandomChoice[{l + (1 - l) (z + (1 - z) (1 - sigma[b, c, d])), 
     1 - l - (1 - 
         l) (z + (1 - z) (1 - sigma[b, c, d]))} -> {((l + (1 - 
           l) (z + (1 - z) (1 - sigma[b, c, d]))) d)/(
     1 - p0[b, c, d]), (((1 - l) (1 - z) sigma[b, c, d]) d)/
     p0[b, c, d]}];

trajectories = 
  Table[{NestList[nextc, c0, 80], NestList[nextb, b0, 80], 
    NestList[nextd, d0, 80]}, 200];

ListLinePlot[trajectories, PlotRange -> Full] ```
````

Comment: nextb, nextc and nextd all take 3 arguments. However, you only deliver one.

Comment: @DanielHuber thanks for your reply,. You are right of course. However, I cannot add other arguments using NestList. Is there another command to do the same thing correctly? Thanks again.

Comment: I am not sure what you want. However, to call e.g. netb with 1 variable and 2 fix arguments, you may write `NestList[nextc[#,fixc,fixd]&, c0, 80]`. Note also that your "Table" creates 200 times the same result.